# Standardising variables in mixed models

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, standardization

I have rainfall and temperature data across multiple locations and I want to model yield as a function of these two. I know rainfall and temperature relationship is not linear i.e. there is a gain in yield first and then a decline with these two increasing.

I did this:

```
dat$temp2 <- temp^2
dat$rain2 <- rain^2

dat.z <- scale(dat[,2:5], center = T)

lmer(yield ~ temp + temp2 + rain + rain2 + (1| loc), data = dat.z)
```

I wanted to ask do I have to standarise temp and rain first and then take the square or the above step is fine?

Comment: What does `dat[,2:5]` contain? Is it `temp`, `temp2`, `rain`, and `rain2`?

Comment: `dat[,2:5]` contains `temp`, `temp2`, `rain`, and `rain2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better way to model non-linear effects is using splines. This can be easily done in R using the **splines** package. For example, the code below specifies a natural cubic spline with three degrees of freedom for `temp` and `rain`:

```
library(splines)
fm <- lmer(yield ~ ns(temp, 3) + ns(rain, 3) + (1 | loc), data = dat)
summary(fm)
```

You can test whether the effect of `temp` is linear using:

```
gm <- lmer(yield ~ temp + ns(rain, 3) + (1 | loc), data = dat)
anova(gm, fm)
```

P.s., to decrease potentially multicollinearity issues between polynomial terms, typically you first standardize and then calculate the polynomials. However, a better way is to use orthogonal polynomials that resolve these issues. This is available in R using the `poly()` function, i.e., you could use:

```
lmer(yield ~ poly(temp, 2) + poly(rain, 2) + (1 | loc), data = dat)
```

Answer (score 1):

+1 to Dimitri's answer because it is on the right track. Using splines to account for non-linearities is generally a better solution than immediately transforming our variables

Some complementary points:

1. Kenward-Roger's approximation from [`pbkrtest`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pbkrtest/index.html) or in general using to the package [`lmerTest`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lmerTest/index.html) probably is a better idea than using `stats::anova` from the `lmer` object. The tests in these packages are specifically design to deal with subtleties of mixed effects models.
2. Using generalised additive mixed models through `gamm` (or `gamm4` - from the packages [`mgcv`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mgcv/index.html)/[`gamm4`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gamm4/index.html) respectively) is a more stream-lined overall approach than using `lmer` and `splines`  as it has in-built checks on accessing and visualising the spline fit (e.g. see function `gam.check` from `mgcv` or check the package [`RLRsim`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RLRsim/index.html) that specifically focuses on questions like ["*is this smooth effect significantly different from a constant effect?*"](https://github.com/fabian-s/RLRsim)).
3. Two relevant papers on the matter of selecting relevant effects are: Scheipl et al. (2008) [*Size and power of tests for a zero random effect variance or polynomial regression in additive and linear mixed models*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947307004306) and Greven and Kneib (2010) [*On the behaviour of marginal and conditional AIC in linear mixed models*](https://academic.oup.com/biomet/article-abstract/97/4/773/241321).